# How to manually introduce a script for testing on Firebug or Chrome's developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebug

I'd like to test how my script works on different sites. I wonder if it is possible to use the developer tools to execute it. I tried adding it to the  tag but it doesn't execute.

Does someone know of any other method?

(I'm not sure if this is the right site. I don't think it doesn't have much to do with programming, and it is more about how to use the developer tools, so I thought of this places rather than stackoverflow)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by introducing this in the console:

```
var script1 = document.createElement("script");
var script2 = document.createElement("script");
var head = document.querySelector("head");
var text = 'myscript();';
script2[(script2.innerText===undefined?"textContent":"innerText")] = text;

script1.setAttribute("src", "http://mysite.myscript.js");
head.appendChild(script1);
script1.onload = function(){ head.appendChild(script2) };
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the Firebug's [include()](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Include) command.

Florent

Comment: is there something similar in chrome?

Comment: AFAICT, no. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#additional-apis

Answer (score 0):

The different devtools have editors allowing you to execute JavaScript code in them.

In Firebug this is the so-called [Command Editor](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Editor), the Firefox DevTools have something called [Scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad). Those and the Chrome DevTools also allow you to write multi-line code by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> within their command lines.

*Note:* Scripts executed this way are just temporarily available within the page. After a page reload they are gone again.